# Where to find API documentation for NVIDIA 3D Vision?

Tags: c++, winapi, api, 3d, nvidia

I'd like to start coding for NVIDIA 3D Vision and wonder where can I find the documentation for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs should be on the [nVidia developer site](http://developer.nvidia.com/page/home.html), though I think that it may be called 3D sterio there. As there isn't a visible heading for either, the info you're looking for may be included in the OpenGL or DirectX docs.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is very very old but I was looking for the same information and have found these links to be useful.

The GDC 2009 PowerPoint that David mentioned:
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/presentations/2009/GDC/GDC09-3DVision-The_In_and_Out.pdf

A PDF put out by Nvidia: 
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/whitepapers/2010/NVIDIA%203D%20Vision%20Automatic.pdf

These stackoverflow questions are handy:

[NV_STEREO_IMAGE_SIGNATURE and DirectX 10/11 (nVidia 3D Vision)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377861/nv-stereo-image-signature-and-directx-10-11-nvidia-3d-vision)

[Nvidia 3d Video using DirectX11 and SlimDX in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277069/nvidia-3d-video-using-directx11-and-slimdx-in-c-sharp)

Also there were a number of good topics in the nvidia developers forum, but the forum remains down due to last July's hacker attack. Nvidia promised to restore the old content once they eventually get a new forum up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the main page for 3D Stereo Development http://developer.nvidia.com/object/3d_stereo_dev.html

Some of the links are outdated, as there are new technical presentations at GDC 2009 and SIGGRAPH 2009 (just given yesterday, in fact!).  We will be getting those updated soon!