# Programmaticaly enable stereoscopic 3D in the graphic card

Tags: c#, opengl, xna, stereo-3d

We have a NVIDIA Quadro 5000 and want to set at the beginning of our C#-program the following settings in the graphics card, so that the screen automatically detects the 3D application.

The following settings need to be set:

- Stereoscopic Settings: Enable Stereoscopic 3D
- stereo display mode: Generic Active Stereo
- Enable Stereo: On
- Vertical Sync: On

Is this possible, maybe even with XNA?

Comment: Du meinst du bestimmt die Einstellungen der Graka Softsare oder? So spontan würde ich sagen die Einstellungen sind vielleicht irgendwo in der Registry hinterlegt. Mal geschaut?

Comment: AFAIK, you could easily create a NVIDIA Profile for Your application.

Comment: Nein, in der Registry haben wir noch nicht geschaut, werden wir mal machen.Aber gibt es da nicht irgendwelche Funktionen von XNA, wie vielleicht EnableStereoMode(true), oder irgendwie sowas?

Comment: @Flater We did't tried anything yet, beacause we're still looking for the best solution!

Comment: @Rekin A Profile on a single computer is maybe not a good solution, because the software is running on many computers.

Comment: @OP: Ok, sounds reasonable. I don't really think there's a good programming solution available. I would go with a custom installer script (from NSIS, WiX or InstallShield) which would set the required profile and fail to install at all if it's not possible (no NVidia gpu). It would be quite difficult to handle it properly with some custom register/native code calls from within the application itself.

Comment: Oh, there are some XNA Stereopgraphic examples, but it seems all being handled manually. http://xnacommunity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Stereo&ProjectName=xnacommunity

Comment: Actually you normally do not want some automatic stereoscopification of your program. Explicit stereo always delivers better quelity. Either by rendering for each eye separately, or by using multi-render-target rendering with having a the fragment shader apply parallax shifting.

Comment: @datenwolf: Always? What about stereographic hardware, like VR glasses and screens? Wouldn't the explicit way inhibit the hardware support?

Comment: @Rekin: How do you think VR glasses and screen work? You need to feed them two pictures. One for the left eye, one for the right eye. Those images must be generated somehow. Either you do this explicit by rendering those two views, or implicit, by letting the driver derive a per pixel parallax shift from the finished rendering and its depth buffer contents.

Comment: maybe it is possible to switch the global preset (grafics-profile) through code?!?!

Comment: @MaxPower yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago and found that you can use an API called NVAPI provided by Nvidia. Please see this topic:
[How do you prevent Nvidia's 3D Vision from kicking in? (HOW TO CALL NVAPI FROM .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956252/how-do-you-prevent-nvidias-3d-vision-from-kicking-in-how-to-call-nvapi-from)