# C# PictureBox transparency with c++ lib drawing into UserControl

Tags: c#, dll, transparency, picturebox

I've created a custom .NET `MyUserControl` which uses a 3rd party c++ library to draw on the `MyUserControl` using the `MyUserControl.Control.Handle`.

When I place a child control (i.e. PictureBox) with `BackgroundColor = Transparent` over the `MyUserControl`, the transparency of picturebox does not work - the picturebox shows the original background color of `MyUserControl` -> as if the actual drawing by the lib is ignored.

Is there some way how to setup the picturebox so it is still transparent over `MyUserControl`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent background Label over PictureBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387267/transparent-background-label-over-picturebox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked:

[Overlay WinForms controls on DirectX content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543055/overlay-winforms-controls-on-directx-content)

Although there is one caveat. The `PictureBox` is actually used to draw the rubber band selection rectangle for mouse. Clearing up the top `PictureBox`, since it is transparent, requires invalidating the underlying `MyUserControl` which lies beneath it. Invalidating just the `PictureBox` is enough to display new canvas drawings in 'PictureBox' (current rubber band), but this doesn't clear up the old canvas drawings (previous rubber band).

This introduces a small flicker. If anybody has an idea for this, please post.